# Laptop turns on after turning off

Tags: linux-mint, laptop, bios

I installed Linux Mint and now my laptop turns on after turning off. In BIOS there is no option to switch the boot mode to Legacy/UEFI.

Comment: It's not clear to me what the OS is doing in relation to this problem.

Comment: As this is most certainly BIOS related, as such does not relate to this site. Or faulty hardware. You should try ServerFault.

Comment: You should try to play with the BIOS's power options, mainly focusing on ACPI.  Knowing the exact command you used to turn it off could also help you get answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've experienced the same problem with a HP laptop running Fedora.  In my case, I discovered I could minimize the odds of the laptop turning itself again by disconnecting the AC adapter some minutes or seconds before turning it off (so at the moment of the poweroff it would run on batteries).